# RAM/Hard Drive space occupied as I run a C++ code on MAC?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind

I compile a C++ code (C++11, with STL libraries) and run it on my MAC. As the simulation progresses, I notice that after a while, the space on my hard drive starts being occupied to the point where if I don't stop the code, it can freeze my machine. I tried `valgrind` (mandatorily on a smaller problem size) to find any memory leaks, but I don't. Unfortunately, the actual problem size is too big that it won't' be possible to run `valgrind` on it.

What maybe the problem? Is it a  potential memory leak? 
PS: If it helps, I am using OS X 10.9.5 and compile my CPP code using `g++` command.

edit: Checking the `Activity Monitor`, the memory does not seem to constantly increase on my MAC. This makes it even more peculiar.

edit2: I was able to track down the problem in my code. A `std::vector` was mistakenly constantly extended via `push_back` calls. That's why `valgrind` did not report a memory leak either. Interesting observation: On OSX, the actual RAM was not being used up as the program size grew bigger. OSX decided to use the hard drive space instead. On Linux (CentOS), RAM was constantly occupied by the code until OS killed the job.

Comment: What code are you executing ? Is it filling up hard drive or you RAM ?

Comment: Thanks Arunmu@Arunmu. It is just computations. So, only RAM. It is a code which uses vectors to do some Graph/Tree search.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. Hard to tell what's going on without seeing your program.

Comment: @Is it high CPU usage then, if you memory is not increasing ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks. I tried `valgrind` on a smaller problem size and there was no memory leak. Unfortunately, the code is O(1000) lines, not sure if it helps to dump it here.

Comment: @Arunmu Yes. High CPU usage (searching large Graph/Trees).

Comment: @MomoPP Then it will probably help to probe the running stack frames using `gdb` or `pstack`.

Comment: You better change your title to RAM space and not Hard Drive Space, they are totally different and might confuse someone down the line.

Comment: @Arunmu, @rlam12. Thanks for the suggestions. I was able to track down the issue in my code. A `std::vector` was mistakenly constantly extended via `push_back`. That's why I `valgrind` did not report a memory leak.  Interesting observation: On `OSX`, the actual RAM was not being used up as the program size grew bigger. `OSX` decided to use hard drive instead.  On Linux (CentOS), RAM was constantly occupied by the code until OS killed the job.